# netTcpBinding/BasicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, basichttpbinding

Can someone help to what are the major diff between netTcpBinding v/s BasicHttpBinding ?

In my current project we convert BasicHttpBinding to netTcpBinding and get performance issue, it start timing out even thou the value in BizTalk is set to 1:00:00. We couldn't figure out why ?

Answer (score 5):

netTcp and basicHttp bindings use entirely different transport mechanisms: TCP instead of HTTP. In theory, the binary encoding of TCP should be faster than the text encoding of HTTP.

As discussed [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2011/04/04/how-fast-are-my-services-is-nettcpbinding-really-that-fast.aspx), netTcpBinding may not be as fast, because of additional security overhead and/or contention:

> By default, NetTcpBinding enables certain levels of security add
>   overhead to the message processing pipeline of the WCF runtime.
>   Additionally, the NetTcpBinding also enables the port sharing feature
>   which means that your WCF host won’t have exclusive access to the port
>   and instead might share it with other applications. This might get
>   very interesting if you are hosting your service in a Windows Server
>   2008 or Windows 7 environment given that there are a number of Windows
>   applications that rely on NetTcpBinding endpoints. Finally, the
>   default values for theListenBacklog and MaxConnections settings are
>   set to 10 which is far from optimal for a large number of clients.

Also note that without more information on what part of communication is timing out, it's difficult to say the exact cause. Remember, each side of the transaction has different timeout settings for Open, Close, and Send or Receive.